# SOLR LTR score calculation based on original score

Tags: solr, ltr

I'm trying to come up with rescoring option to avoid noise for searchterm using LTR.

**Usecase**

Search term: test returns 20k records, max score is 240, and least score is 1.2
Now, I wanted to avoid results with score < 12.
12 = (20000/240) (5% off 20000)

**LTR Store**

(numFound/maxscore) ((5/100)*numFound)

/schema/feature-store/*DEFAULT*

```
[
    {
    "name" : "documentQuality",
    "class" : "org.apache.solr.ltr.feature.SolrFeature",
    "params" : {
      "q" : "{!func} product(div(numFound, maxscore), product(0.05, numFound)"
    }
  }
]
```

/schema/model-store/

```
{
  "class" : "org.apache.solr.ltr.model.LinearModel",
  "name" : "myModel",
  "features" : [
    { "name" : "documentQuality" }
        
  
  ],"params" : {
    "weights" : {
      "documentQuality" : 1.0
      
    }
  }
}
```

Log feature

`/query?q=drills&rq={!ltr model=myModel reRankDocs=100}&fl=name,id,price,score,[features]`

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception from createWeight for SolrFeature [name=documentQuality, params={q={!func} product(div(numFound, maxscore), product(0.05, numFound)}] Failed to parse feature query.

Looks like these variables are not visible, is there any alternate to perform this rescoring.?